# ZSH wildcard expression limiting repetition support?

Tags: regular-expression, zsh, wildcards

Does anyone know if there is a way to incorporate repetition constraints into ZSH wildcard expressions?

For example, to match all files starting with "ABC" following by one or more numbers, using grep one could do:

```
ls | grep -e "ABC[0-9]\+"
```

Is there any way to do this directly with ZSH glob strings? Something along the lines of:

```
ls "ABC[0-9]\+"
```

I've looked through the [docs for ZSH](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) and Googled for something like this, but so far have not found any such support.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: if you scroll down to `14.8.1 Glob Operators` you'll find `<[x]-[y]>` and `x##`... so in your case `<->` or `[0-9]##` (with `setopt extendedglob`)

Comment: Great! I completely missed that -- was looking for something like `\+` or `{n,}`. This works perfectly.

Comment: You could do it with `+` too if you used `kshglob` (_it's on the same page_): `print -rl ABC+([0-9])` though keep in mind [you also need  `unsetopt bareglobqual` if not in ksh emulation mode](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00484.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use `##` to match one or more occurrence of `[0-9]` like:

```
ABC[0-9]##
```

This requires `extendedglob` to be set, which is by default. If unset, set it first:

```
setopt extendedglob
```

**Example:**

```
% print -l ABC*
ABC
ABC75475
ABC8
ABC90

% print -l ABC[0-9]##
ABC75475
ABC8
ABC90
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Out of curiosity, do you know if there is any similar syntax for specifying a min/max number of repeats? e.g. something like "[0-9a-z]{2,5}"?

Comment: @KeithHughitt Just added this :)

Comment: I saw that you added note about extendedglob immediately after I posted comment, so I edited that part out. Thanks for including that!

Comment: @KeithHughitt regarding your second requirement, i don't think this can be done with globbing with `zsh` (at least i'm not aware of one). Btw you can take a look at numeric range matching via `<X-Y>`

Comment: @heemayl: you can, using `(#cN,M)` globbing flag.

Comment: @cuonglm Thank you very much, i didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

Scroll down to “[Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)”, and enable either [`extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) (which should be the default, but isn't for backward compatibility) or [`ksh_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSH_005fGLOB). Both zsh's extended globs and ksh's have the full power of regular expressions.

```
ERE syntax      ksh glob      zsh extended glob
(foo)*          *(foo)        (foo)#
(foo)+          +(foo)        (foo)##
(foo)?          ?(foo)        (|foo)
(foo|bar)       @(foo|bar)    (foo|bar)
```

Keep in mind that most tools that use regular expressions use them as *search* patterns that must match a substring, but globs are always used as patterns that must match the whole string. For example `foofoobar` does not match the zsh glob `(foo)##`, since after `foofoo` there's some text left over.

Zsh has additional operators that don't extend the expressive power but make some expressions easier to write. The operators `^` and `~` (`extended_glob`) and `!(…)` (`ksh_glob`) provide negation, e.g. `^foo` or `!(foo)` matches anything except `foo`, which in regex syntax requires the unwieldy `|[^f].*|f[^o].*|fo[^o].*`. The operator `<…-…>` (zsh-specific, does not require `extended_glob`) matches any integer (in decimal notation) in a range, e.g. `<3-11>` matches `3` and `10` but not `30` or `1`.

So, excluding issues like unprintable characters, `ls | grep -e "ABC[0-9]\+"` can be written in ways such as

```
print -lr -- *ABC[0-9]##*(N)      # requires extended_glob
print -lr -- *ABC+([0-9])*(N)      # requires ksh_glob
print -lr -- *ABC+<->(N)
```

But since “one or more digit then anything” is equivalent to “a digit then anything”, it can also be written

```
print -lr -- *ABC[0-9]*(N)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `extendedglob` enabled:

```
$ setopt extendedglob
$ print -rl -- perl[[:digit:]]##
perl5
```

or with `kshglob` enabled and `bareglobqual` disabled:

```
$ setopt kshglob
$ unsetopt bareglobqual
$ print -rl -- perl+([[:digit:]])
perl5
```

Note that using `[:digit:]` to match everything considered digit in current locale. If you want to match `0` through `9` only, set `LC_ALL=C` or using literally `[0123456789]`.

---

You can specify number of match, like regular expression `{n,m}` using `(#cN,M)` globbing flag anywhere that `#` and `##`operators can be used, except in `(*/)#` and `(*/)##`:

```
$ print -rl -- perl[[:digit:]](#c1)
perl5
$ print -rl -- perl[[:digit:]](#c2)
zsh: no matches found: perl[[:digit:]](#c2)
```